# Unable to find the PCLstorage path in Android

Tags: android, xamarin, cross-platform, storage, portable-class-library

I created a PCL project in Xamarin and I am trying to save files with a cross-platform solution using PCLstorage.
This is my code (from the example in [PCLstorage website](https://pclstorage.codeplex.com/))

```
IFolder rootFolder = FileSystem.Current.LocalStorage;
IFolder folder = await rootFolder.CreateFolderAsync("FolderName", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
IFile file = await folder.CreateFileAsync("filename.txt", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
await file.WriteAllTextAsync("text");
```

Now, I want to know where this file is saved. 
In Windows Phone, using WP power tools, I can explore the isolatedStorage of my app and I find and open the txt file. While, in Android, I can't find the folder created! 
The path would be "data/data/com.appname.test/files/ but I don't find it!

Someone can help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will be able to access to that folder only from the device (not from PC using USB cable) and only with root rights, so you need to root your device (try SuperSu from GooglePlay it work for most of the devices)

Comment: Ok, this is interesting!
However, I create a folder, write a txt file like in the code above. Then I try to read it. Everything works. But, if I restart the app and I just try to read the file created before, I have a file excpetion (it says the folder doesn't exist, neither the file). This happened only on Android, while on Win Phone everythings works. 
I don't understand why

Comment: How you restarting the app? You restarting it using Visual/Xamarin Studio? Or just relaunching it after it was deployed on device?

Comment: Oh..I restarted it using Visual Studio.
If I just relaunch the app, it works! I think it should be right!
Thank you

Comment: So if you are restarting it with Studio the go to the Tools -> Options -> Xamarin -> Android Settings and check "Preserve application data/cache on device between deploys" it will keep files between restarts of the app

Comment: You can also use an emulator which will allow you to through the data on the device

Answer (score 0):

if you want to store it in external storage you can pass the folder path and create the file. so you can access that file physically.

```
string path="path";
IFolder rootFolder = await FileSystem.Current.GetFolderFromPathAsync(path);
IFolder folder = await rootFolder.CreateFolderAsync("folder", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
IFile file = await folder.CreateFileAsync("file", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
```